# how to handle errors in json web tokens

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, mern

i am beginner and trying to handle jwt verification.
In the below function i want that if the user access token is expired then i generate new access token on the basis of refresh token.

```
import { asyncHandler } from "../utils/asyncHandler.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { generateAccessTokenAndRefreshToken } from "../utils/generateTokens.js";
import { User } from "../models/user.model.js";

export const isRequestAuthorized = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log("Start");
    const userAccessToken =
      req.cookies?.accessToken ||
      req.header("Authorization").replace("Bearer ", "");

    const userRefreshToken = req.cookies?.refreshToken;
    console.log(
      "Access token: " +
        userAccessToken +
        " refresh token: " +
        userRefreshToken,
    );

    if (!userAccessToken || !userRefreshToken) {
      throw new ApiError(404, "Auth Tokens missing");
    }

    const decodedAccessToken = await jwt.verify(
      userAccessToken,
      process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    );
    console.log(decodedAccessToken);
    //if access token is expired then checking refresh token and updating both token
    if (!decodedAccessToken) {
      console.log("access token is expired");
      const decodedRefreshToken = await jwt.verify(
        userRefreshToken,
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
      );
      console.log("isRefreshTokenValid", decodedAccessToken);
      if (!decodedRefreshToken) {
        throw new ApiError(404, "Auth Tokens expired");
      }

      const { accessToken, refreshToken } =
        generateAccessTokenAndRefreshToken(decodedRefreshToken);

      const user = await user.findById(decodedRefreshToken);

      if (userRefreshToken !== user.refreshToken && user.isAdmin == false) {
        throw new ApiError(404, "UnAuthorized request");
      }

      const options = { httpOnly: true, secure: true };
      res.user = user;
      res
        .cookie("accessToken", accessToken, options)
        .cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, options)
        .save();
      next();
    }

    const user = await User.findById(decodedAccessToken);

    if (userRefreshToken !== user.refreshToken && user.isAdmin == false) {
      throw new ApiError(404, "UnAuthorized request");
    }

    res.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});
```

the error i am facing is that when jwt is verifying my access token it ends the function and throw the error that accesstoken is expired where as i want to continue my function and want to generate new accessToken on basis of refresh token. please tell me the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, if there's an error while verifying the access token (due to expiration), it catches the error, logs that the access token is expired, and then continues with the logic to refresh the access token using the refresh token.

```
export const isRequestAuthorized = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log("Start");
    const userAccessToken =
      req.cookies?.accessToken ||
      req.header("Authorization").replace("Bearer ", "");

    const userRefreshToken = req.cookies?.refreshToken;
    console.log(
      "Access token: " +
        userAccessToken +
        " refresh token: " +
        userRefreshToken,
    );

    if (!userAccessToken || !userRefreshToken) {
      throw new ApiError(404, "Auth Tokens missing");
    }

    let decodedAccessToken;
    try {
      decodedAccessToken = await jwt.verify(
        userAccessToken,
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
      );
      console.log(decodedAccessToken);
    } catch (accessTokenError) {
      console.log("Access token is expired");
      // Continue with the logic to refresh the access token
    }

    if (!decodedAccessToken) {
      const decodedRefreshToken = await jwt.verify(
        userRefreshToken,
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
      );
      console.log("isRefreshTokenValid", decodedAccessToken);
      if (!decodedRefreshToken) {
        throw new ApiError(404, "Auth Tokens expired");
      }

      const { accessToken, refreshToken } =
        generateAccessTokenAndRefreshToken(decodedRefreshToken);

      const user = await User.findById(decodedRefreshToken);

      if (userRefreshToken !== user.refreshToken && user.isAdmin == false) {
        throw new ApiError(404, "UnAuthorized request");
      }

      const options = { httpOnly: true, secure: true };
      res.user = user;
      res
        .cookie("accessToken", accessToken, options)
        .cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, options)
        .save();
      next();
    } else {
      const user = await User.findById(decodedAccessToken);

      if (userRefreshToken !== user.refreshToken && user.isAdmin == false) {
        throw new ApiError(404, "UnAuthorized request");
      }

      res.user = user;
      next();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Verification of access tokens happens on the _server_, but the in order to [refresh the access token](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RefreshingAccessToken), the server needs the client secret, which is only known to the _client_. Your code, which runs on the server, cannot therefore "Continue with the logic to refresh the access token", because it does not have the client secret.